# Html links to other pages, images and Css not working in Docker container?

Tags: html, css, node.js, docker

I am working to deploy a nodejs application using Docker. The application has been deployed before and has worked absolutely fine.  The packages for npm and bower all gets installed correctly.  I have set the working directory as follows:

```
WORKDIR     /opt/ab/zyx/app/
```

My index.html, about.html, etc are in the app folder.  The css are in a folder called css sitting in the app folder too.  There are bower_components folder in the zyx folder.  In the index.html file I have links to about.html and about.html. Currently the link to both these pages is like this.

```
<li><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#/faq">FAQ</a></li>
```

And this is not working, however when I change the link to this it starts working

```
<li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
```

If I remove the .html extension it stops working again.
For bower_components the code is like this and not working.

```
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

The same is the case for css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/abc.css"/>
```

I am confused if Docker interprets these links and path differently. Or I am missing something. I am sure Docker wouldn't want developers to develop code based on their requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try loading fiddler? It should give you a clue on the urls being utilized.